# C# SSIS pkg.Execute(null,null,dtsEvents,null,null) returns "Failed" with no events

Tags: c#, ssis

I'm just dummy in using SSIS&*.dtsx files from C#. Now I have WindowsForms project and OnClick handler with this code:

```
                   .....
                   string pkgLocation;  
                   Package pkg;  
                   Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application app;  
                   DTSExecResult pkgResults;
                   DTSEvents dtsEvents=new DTSEvents();
                   pkgLocation = System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath+ @"\" + @"3StreamsImport.dtsx";
                   app = new Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application();
                   app.PackagePassword = "abudfv";
                   app.EnableDump = true;
                   app.DumpOnAnyError = true; 
                   pkg = app.LoadPackage(pkgLocation, dtsEvents,true);
                   try {
                            pkgResults = pkg.Execute(null,null,dtsEvents,null,null);
                    }catch(System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException ex) {
                             Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
                    }
                      .......
```

"3Streamsimport.dtsx" file was created with SqlServer management studio for SqlServer 2016 and is working fine from standard Еxecute Package Utility. Loading package in my code passes fine too. But executing fails allways! dtsEvents is instanceof object that implements all from IDTSEvents interface.
Dear ALL, who can help with definitions of ways to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since I tried, so I don't know if later versions have improved anything, but I was never able to get an SSIS package to execute from C# the way you are trying to do.

What I eventually did was create a job that executed the package, and used C# to start the job.   It worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

***Solved!*** All C# code is fine. As addition I'm implemented IDTSLogging. After changing "exectute" call to

```
pkgResults = pkg.Execute(null,null,dtsEvents,new DTSLogging(),null);
```

all events are firing smoothly. I don'nt know/ why, but it is working.
Now about DTSX- file: It was my mistake in project and the proper copy was simply in other place! :-(
Sorry :-(